# how could i get two next words of specific word from string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, loops

I have a list of specific words

```
['to', 'with', 'in', 'for']
```

I want to make a function, which takes a sentence and if there is a word form my list, it should select the next two words after it and put them joined to the list(i need it for a part of my sentence generator). For example:

```
sentence = 'In the morning I went to the store and then to the restaurant'
```

I want to get

```
['tothe', 'tostore', 'tothe', 'torestaurant']
```

I wrote this code:

```
preps = ['to', 'with', 'in', 'for']
def nextofnext_words_ofnegs(sentence):
    list_of_words = sentence.split()
    next_word = []
    for i in list_of_words:
        for j in preps:
            if i == j:
                next_word.append(j + list_of_words[list_of_words.index(i) + 1])
                next_word.append(j + list_of_words[list_of_words.index(i) + 2])
    return next_word
```

However i get this:

```
['tothe', 'tostore', 'tothe', 'tostore']
```

Instead of this:

```
['tothe', 'tostore', 'tothe', 'torestaurant']
```

Comment: *next two words* - what if there are No next words ?

Comment: I will write a limitations for sentences before it, now i only consider cases when there are two next words.

Comment: `.index()` finds the FIRST occurrence of the indexed term, regardless of where in the list it is called. You need to iterate your indices at the same time

Comment: Just an advice. If you have a solution for the problem, and you are not getting an error but a incorrect output, you probably want to debug your program to see, step by step, what is going on and understand why the output is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work to give you what you want. Note that you can use the "in" operator in Python to check if the word exists in your string list, there is no need to loop the list here in this case. Also as mentioned above, using of .index is insufficient here, you can use enumerate to get the index as well as the item in the list.

```
preps = ['to', 'with', 'in', 'for']
def nextofnext_words_ofnegs(sentence):
    list_of_words = sentence.split()
    next_word = []
    for idx, word in enumerate(list_of_words):
        if word in preps:
            next_word.append(word + list_of_words[idx + 1])
            next_word.append(word + list_of_words[idx + 2])
    return next_word
```